# Keeping track of dependency revisions

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, dependencies

I have a project with several dependencies that are in various repositories. Each time I commit changes to my project, I make sure I write the revision numbers of all the dependent repositories so that in the event I ever have to come back to this revision (let's call it 5), I can immediately know which revisions of the dependent repositories revision 5 is guaranteed to work with, update the dependencies to the specified revisions, compile and run the project. So for example if I have:

```
 Dep1 @ Revisions 10
 Dep2 @ Revisions 20 
 Dep3 @ Revisions 10 
 Proj @ Revisions 35
```

And let's say that when **Proj** was on revision `17`, the **Dep1** revision was `5`, **Dep2** revision was `13` and **Dep3** revision was `3`. So in my SVN logs, I recorded something like this:

`!! Works with Dep1 Rev 5, Dep2 Rev 13, Dep3 Rev 3`

To me this seems primitive and makes me believe that there is a better way to do it. Now in one of my other questions, Ivy Dependency Manager has been recommended. I have not looked at it in detail yet (seems complicated and yet another thing I must learn). To me it seems like the log of SVN (and Mercurial etc.) could have been split into `Log` and `Dependencies (if any)` where the latter could be switched off if there were no dependencies (unless of course I am unaware of an easier/better solution). This would allow for a cleaner log that maybe even warned at each new commit to check the previously defined dependencies again and make sure they have not changed.

So, I was wondering how everyone manages this situations and if you have any tips, techniques, programs, suggestions that you can offer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the dependant repositories as a subproject, submodule, or external depending on whatever your version control system calls it.

That way, you can keep the dependencies in sync as you work on the repository, however, it is still manual.

Even better is to write tests, so that you can automatically determine that the dependency satisfies all the requirements.

Comment: "git" makes this really easy, in my experience.

Comment: Now when you say in sync, do you mean that if I update to a previous revision of my project repository, the revision number of the sub-repositories (nested repositories in mercurial I believe) will be recorded with each commit? I am testing it out and I don't see any signs that will tell me this is happening... if it does, this is exactly the solution I am looking for

Comment: for Mercurial, yes, this is what happens. You need to tell Mercurial to track the subrepositories by adding a .hgsub file, and when you commit, Mercurial will add or update the .hgsubstate file with specific revisions of those sub-repositores, and these two files are versioned in your repository. This means that if you update back to an older version, those two files tells Mercurial which sub-repositories it needs, where to get them, and which revisions to update each to.

Answer (score 1):

How do you compile your dependencies and how connected are they to your project? If they're not part of your project, compile them to .dll (or .jar or whatever) and commit it to your project. You can note the version and any notes in commit comment or a readme file (also commited to your project). And then work with that, and periodically update the dependency .dll.

Comment: +1 as this is a good solution for smaller scaled projects. The problem with that however, is that I have to include the header files in the repository. So if the library is very large (Havok, PhysX, Boost) then that is a lot of header files that are cluttering the repository.